# Detecting when a user is beginning to edit an UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am wondering if it is possible to detect if a user is beginning to edit a text view (so that I can make certain adjustments to the view). Would I have to detect for the keyboard instead?

Comment: To be clear, do you want to detect when focus moves to the text view or do you actually want to know when the user makes an actual text change in the text view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible using `UITextView`'s delegate. You can see documentation of the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html).

There is a nice tutorial found [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_uitextview_uitextviewdelegate_2/) that will show you how to detect these interactions using the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [UITextViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html). Implement `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` if you want to react while the user is typing or `textViewDidChange:` otherwise.

Edit: If you are only interested when the text fields becomes the first responder (i.e. the user sets the focus), use `textViewDidBeginEditing`.

Comment: This is not the right delegate method to detect when a user begins editing. Since the question asks about detecting the keyboard, the question really want to know when the text view gets focus.

Comment: Well, depends on how you define "editing". `textViewDidBeginEditing` is called right when the users sets the cursor, not when he actually edits the text in terms of adding or removing characters.

Comment: See the comment I just left on the question.

Comment: @ashtom He wants to know when the keyboard appears, as stated in the question. So `textViewDidBeginEditing` is the way to go. (I'm assuming the textView gets covered up by the keyboard so he wants to translate it when the keyboard displays so that it's visible.)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I initially assumed the question was about focus but the wording of the question talks about "begins editing". It is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @rmaddy I can see it going both ways.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: Edited my answers to reflect both ways.

Comment: What's funny is the accepted answer doesn't clarify what the OP actually wanted. But obviously the OP got the needed answer so it doesn't matter any more. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign your textView's delegate in your xib file (or programmatically)

Use one of these:

`- (BOOL)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {`

`- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {`